# How to count the number of letters in a string with a list of sample?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
value = 'bcdjbcdscv'
value = 'bcdvfdvdfvvdfvv'
value = 'bcvfdvdfvcdjbcdscv'

def count_letters(word, char):
    count = 0
    for c in word:
     if char == c:
      count += 1
    return count
```

How to count the number of letters in a string with a list of sample? I get nothing in my python shell when I wrote the above code in my python file.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: To get some output, you need to call the function and then print the result.

Comment: @thefourtheye, the expected output is the total/sum of character in the string.

Comment: @NPE, 
value = 'bcdjbcdscv'

def count_letters(word, char):
  x = count_letters(value, char)
  count = 0
  for c in word:
    if char == c:
      count += 1
      print x
  return count
but do not work, what is the mistakes?

Comment: should say I want to calculate the length of string and I have to write my code in python file instead of python shell because I want to to loop for a list of sample and count the length of string in each sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

functions need to be *called*, and the return values need to be *printed* to the stdout:

```
In [984]: value = 'bcvfdvdfvcdjbcdscv'

In [985]: count_letters(value, 'b')
Out[985]: 2

In [987]: ds=count_letters(value, 'd') #if you assign the return value to some variable, print it out:

In [988]: print ds
4
```

### EDIT:

On **calculating the length of the string**, use python builtin function `len`:

```
In [1024]: s='abcdefghij'

In [1025]: len(s)
Out[1025]: 10
```

You'd better **google it** with some keywords like *"python get length of a string"* before you ask on SO, it's much time saving :)

### EDIT2:

**How to calculate the length of several strings with one function call?**

use [var-positional parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-parameter) `*args`, which accepts an arbitrary sequence of positional arguments:

```
In [1048]: def get_lengths(*args):
      ...:     return [len(i) for i in args]

In [1049]: get_lengths('abcd', 'efg', '1234567')
Out[1049]: [4, 3, 7]
```

Comment: how about if I want to count for the total/sum of character in the string instead of only 'b'? Can I write in the python file? instead of python shell, because I will have to loop for a list of sample and count the number of character in each sample.

Comment: @user3340270 what do you mean by `total/sum of character in the string `? calculating the length of the string? or count every char appears in the string?

Comment: value1='qwertyuiop'
value2='asdfghjkl'
value3='zxcvbnm'

output:
10
9
7

Comment: yes, get it. if I have 5 samples and can only run for 1 time to get all the output? I am new learner of python

Answer (score 5):

There is a built-in method for this:

```
value.count('c')
```

Comment: what about if I want to calculate the length of string, and I have to write my code in python file instead of python shell because I want to to loop for a list of sample and count the length of string in each sample

Answer (score 1):

First you should probably look at correct indenting and only send in `value`.  Also `value` is being overwritten so the last one will be the actual reference.

Second you need to call the function that you have defined.

```
#value = 'bcdjbcdscv'
#value = 'bcdvfdvdfvvdfvv'

value = 'bcvfdvdfvcdjbcdscv'

def count_letters(word, char):
    count = 0
    for c in word:
        if char == c:
        count += 1
    return count

x = count_letters(value, 'b')
print x
# 2
```

This should produce the result you are looking for.  You could also just call:

```
print value.count('b')
# 2
```

Comment: value = 'bcdjbcdscv'

def count_letters(word, char):
  x = count_letters(value, char)
  count = 0
  for c in word:
    if char == c:
      count += 1
      print x
  return count
but do not work, what is the mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is a built-in method to do this. Simply type:

```
value = 'bcdjbcdscv'    
value.count('c')
```

Comment: value = 'bcdjbcdscv'
value.count('c') ?
I am just new learner.